# Error when fetching data. Sanity studio v3 and React

Tags: reactjs, sanity

[image: This is my schema]
[image: This is where I fetch the data]
[image: This is the error]

It can't find any reason why this wouldn't work. I have watched all tutorials doing the same. Any one have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

there is an extra braces in the query.

Write this:

```
const query = `*[_type == "courses"]{
                title
                }`;
sanityClient.fetch(query)
            .then(data=>setCourses(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

Cannot thank you enough..just braces caused me 2 days..even tried another headless CMS..XD